# Android, how to get Facebook/Twitter/etc contact photos

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, android-contacts

I want to load contact photos for contacts in an app, I know how to do that as there are many tutorials to do that. But these methods(stock android) seems to fail to pull back 3rd party sync'd photos I was wondering if there is a solid and reliable way to do this natively.

This has been asked many times and I can reel off the answers left right and center. Only problem is they don't actually solve the problem. Only create work arounds.

After some extensive searching I came across this:

> There is a bug in android to prevent us to retrieve the contact photo
>   (almost all missing contact photos are facebook profile photo). To
>   solve this, we must sign the APK by the shared cert and force the app
>   running in shared-uid.

I found this on https://sites.google.com/site/t2k269group/development-diary/load-contact-photo can anyone elaborate on how to sign with a shared key and if this would even work?

Of if anyone else actually has a reliable solution that loads contacts photos regardless of what synced them.

Question: Is there a reliable way to load contact photos which includes synced photos not just the ones set on the phone?

Thanks in advance.
Cheers,
Chris

Comment: what you want to do? you want integrate facebook with your application?

Comment: Added to the question:
Question: Is there a reliable way to load contact photos which includes synced photos not just the ones set on the phone?

Answer (score 1):

here u will get Contacts of FB with photos https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples/Hackbook/src/com

Comment: Can you elaborate on wether it uses the interenet to get photos from facebook or from the ContactsProvider? Cheers,Chris

Comment: it users internet to get photos

Comment: Thought you might say that. Thanks for the link, its a solution, but not really answer the question ;)